# How to use cache images for display in flutter until url is loading?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am having a sample application which is having networking images, how to display preloaded cache images when navigating between pages. Because it is taking some time for loading from api calls. instead of placeholder how to display same image which loaded previously.
I am trying to use flutter_cache_manager 0.1.1, cached_network_image 0.4.1+1
plugins but still unable to achieve.

Comment: did you try using FadeInImage?

Comment: cached_network_image should do that automatically - what part of the plugin doesnt do what you'd like?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [FadeInImage](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FadeInImage-class.html) where you can set a placeholder image until the actual image becomes available.
The actual image can come from various `ImageProvider`s like `NetworkImageWithRetry` or similar.